# Delphi Firedac MSSQL copy to different server

Tags: sql-server, delphi, data-synchronization, firedac

i have 2x Firedac Connection on MSSQL.

First table is a source and second table is target, how to synchronize selected tables from source to target ?

Exists in tfdconnection or in tfdtable procedure/function to synchronize or generate SQL script to create table ?

Thanks all. :))

Answer (score 1):

After a long search, I found that they can copy data from source to destination.

You have use FireDac component TFDBatchMove where is select an Reader and Writer.

As Reader/Writer you have use Text/Dataset/SQL component in FireDac ETL group.

Thanks a bye :)

Comment: "After a long search" sorry - but you answered the same day when you asked ;-)

Comment: for me 5 hours is a long :))